# How to resolve 'Sender address rejected' error in nodemailer when sending email from node.js application?

Tags: node.js, forms, email, nodemailer

I’m changing the way of sending contact emails from my website to my corporate email, I’m using `hostinger` as a mail provider, I was previously using php to do this, but it was a little limited, so I decided to use nodejs along with nodemailer, my problem is that when trying to send the email from the web throws the following error:

```
Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553 5.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user test@domain.com
code: 'EENVELOPE',
response: '553 5.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user test@domain.com',
responseCode: 553,
command: 'RCPT TO',
recipient: 'test@domain.com'
```

the code is as follows:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const router = Router();

router.post("/send-email", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, lastName, email, subject, country, whereMeetUs, message } =
    req.body;

  const corpMail = "test@domain.com";
  const password = "pass";

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.hostinger.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: "login",
      user: corpMail,
      pass: password,
    },
  });

  const info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: email,
    to: corpMail,
    subject,
    html: ` 
    <h1>User information</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>User: ${name} ${lastName}</li>
        <li>Mail: ${email}</li>
        <li>Subject: ${subject}</li>
        <li>Country: ${country}</li>
        <li>Where meet us: ${whereMeetUs}</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <p>${message}</p>
    `,
  });

  console.log("Message sent", info.messageId);
  res.redirect("/contact.html");
});

module.exports = router;
```

What I am looking for is that when sending the email from my website, the message received from the address that is written in the form is reflected in the corporate inbox, so that you can respond directly to that address.

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
```

For example if I put `user@example.com` in that input, it is reflected in the inbox that `user@example.com` was who contacted me.